# Reflecting/shared changes amongst groups?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I don't know how to search for something like this on Google so I thought I would ask here.

I am wondering if it is possible to have a group and a duplicate of that group and reflect changes from the original group to the duplicate group automatically.

Any changes like a new layer, a layer edit, deletion of layer, etc. The exception would be a single layer that would be different, like an image.

Is this possible in photoshop?

Comment: Hi Stephan-v, I made some minor edits to your question in hope that it clarifies the question. I do want to know, are you trying to have the changes made from the original group make changes to the duplicate group automatically?

Comment: Yes, or the other way around. Just have them mimic each other with the exception of like a single layer.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using a smart object and just editing the smart object itself. Any instance of that same smart object should reflect the changes.

Comment: I don't think you can add adjustments to smart objects like curves or many others. Three are a couple that will apply like Highlight and Shadow and some filters. But other adjustments like curves will have to be added as layers. Also, there are some other tools that will not apply to SOs until they are rasterized. The idea is appealing but limited in utility in my opinion. Please correct me if I am wrong.